# "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" when saving related entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 2 controllers and repositories, Gifts and Registries.  A gift can have a registry, and when I try to create a new gift I get the error "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

A Gift has the following attributes:

```
public class Gift
{
    public int GiftId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Registry Registry { get; set; }
}
```

My code to add a gift is as follows:

In the controller:

```
    private IGiftRepository _giftRepository;
    private IAccountRepository _accountRepository;

    public GiftController()
    {
        this._giftRepository = new GiftRepository(new ApplicationDbContext());
        this._accountRepository = new AccountRepository(new ApplicationDbContext());
    }

    public GiftController(IGiftRepository giftRepository)
    {
        this._giftRepository = giftRepository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Gift gift)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Registry registry = _accountRepository.GetLoggedInRegistry(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            gift.Registry = registry;

            await _giftRepository.AddGiftAsync(gift);

            return RedirectToAction("Home", "Admin");
        }

        return View(gift);
    }
```

And here is the code in the repository:

```
    public async Task<bool> AddGiftAsync(Gift gift)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Gifts.Add(gift);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

At _content.Gifts.Add(gift) I get the following error: "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker." which I realise is due to the way I've configured my contexts, but I'm not sure what changes I need to make to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize repositories like this:

```
 public GiftController()
 {
     var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
     this._giftRepository = new GiftRepository(context);
     this._accountRepository = new AccountRepository(context);
 }
```